# Firefox-Addon, Javascript doesn't fill <input>

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I am working on an add-on that's supposed to fasten the workflow by filling some fields in a form

I have managed to successfully open a NewBrowser tab and fill-in most of the data, most of because for some reason the `<input>` types don't fill, while the selects and textareas have no issue.

I am using getElementsByName for all elements, because they have names, but no ID -.-'

Example code:

```
//Set "Title" to sever name that was highlighted on rightclick
                var title = document.getElementsByName("title");
                title[0].value="asd";

                var addProbDet = document.getElementsByName("UDF595610900");
                addProbDet[0].value = "Additional Problem Details HERE!!!";



                //Set "Category of Work-SubCategory" to "OS[Other]"
                var workSubCat = document.getElementsByName("UDF654060815");
                workSubCat[0].value = "734918941";


                //Set "Work Queue" to "SYSHOSTING-UNIX [SOLARIS SYS ADMIN]"
                var workQ = document.getElementsByName("UDF581036117");
                workQ[0].value = "1156820601";
```

HTML:

```
<td id="panelCol1_1" width="50%">
  <table class="infoPanels" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="editCellTitle">
          <nobr>
            Title
            <img src="/v/B_1992_1992/image/requiredCheck.gif">
          </nobr>
          <br>
          <nobr>
            <input class="txt" type="text" onfocus="prompt("Enter a title for this request")" maxlength="80" size="32" name="title" tabindex="1">
          </nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="editCellTitle">
          <nobr></nobr>
          <br></br>
          <nobr>
            <select  onfocus="prompt("")" tabindex="4" size="1" name="UDF654060815"></select>
          </nobr>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="editCellTitle">
          <nobr></nobr>
          <br></br>
          <nobr>
            <select onfocus="prompt("")" tabindex="5" size="1"      name="UDF581036117"></select>
          </nobr>
```

So the code above fills The first , and two s.

And input value isn't set for some reason.

The code is in a eventlistener:

```
var baseUrl = this.optickBaseUrl + this.optickParams;
        var newTab = gBrowser.addTab(baseUrl)
        gBrowser.selectedTab =newTab;
        var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(newTab);

        newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
```

If I go to the page and paste the body of this function to the console everything just gets filled nicely.

Comment: Your HTML contains no `<input>`, and your code does not attempt to change the value of an `<input>`. Thus, at best, it is unclear what you are talking about. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: @Makyen Yes it does it is under the first <tr> so I added that to the code

Comment: <input class="txt" type="text" onfocus="prompt("Enter a title for this request")" maxlength="80" size="32" name="title" tabindex="1">

the <input has name="title">
can you please stop nitpicking shit, that doesn't help, my code works just fine, i Just can't copy paste 500 LoC html code, I am searching for elements using getElementsByName and it works, it works in console and as I wrote in my answer below it works now in the addon too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a script doing something on the 'load' event so I just delayed the value change in the input fields by 500 ms

```
setTimeout(function(){

                    //Set "Title" to sever name that was highlighted on rightclick
                    var title = document.getElementsByName("title");
                    title[0].value=selectedText;
}, 500);
```

not very elegant but gets the job done